# Why is dual photo delivery unreliable?

Tags: avfoundation, zooming, ios12, avcapturephotosettings, avcapturephotooutput

[Dual photo delivery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings/2873917-isdualcameradualphotodeliveryena) is supposed to simultaneously capture a photo with the wide and tele cameras, but the tele photo looks like a digitally zoomed version of the wide, not optically zoomed:

[image]

By contrast, here's a 2x photo shot with the iPhone camera app:

[image]

Notice how much clearer it is, as you'd expect from the tele camera?

In case this was an issue with this specific scene, I tried with another, with the same result.

---

In a third case, I found the tele photo returned by dual photo delivery

[image]

to have the same field of view as wide:

[image]

---

In both cases, the EXIF says that it's indeed from the tele camera (F2.4 aperture, 52mm focal length). If it is, why does the content look like a cropped and upscaled version from the wide camera?

This is on iPhone XS running iOS 12.1.3.

I tried doing the following:

- Clean in Xcode
- Clean build folder
- Delete DerivedData
- Uninstalled and reinstalled the app on the iPhone

But none of them helped.